# SubSonic tutorials down due to SilverLight

Tags: subsonic

I'm new to SubSonic (and stackoverflow!) and I just wanted to leave a quick note to the SubSonic team. I'm excited to get started, but unfortunately it looks like all your screencasts are down due to Microsoft ending their SilverLight streaming beta.

Hopefully you have backups (!) and can restore the screencasts without too much trouble - I'd love to see them!

-chrisg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do - I just loaded them up to my server and will push from there using the Tekpub flash player. I just need to rewire the player and I will hopefully get there today.

Comment: Hey, Rob, can you answer this guy's question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311250/subsonic-3-0-mvc-and-paragraph-control he's confused with the Subsonic CMS thing and now I'm confused.  Its spreading, I tell you.