# Subsonic 3.0 MVC and paragraph control

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic, subsonic3

I have a subsonic 3.0 MVC site. Is it CMS based? if yes how can I use subsonic's paragraph control. If it's not CMS based then from where I can get it?

The subsonic 3.0 on http://subsonicproject.com/ does not contains the CMS?

Comment: @coure06 : Subsonic is not a CMS and neither is Asp.Net MVC - Thats said, your question doesnt make sense?

Comment: Yes u r right, but in earlier releases 2.* there was a starter site available for subsonic which also contains the CMS. Is there any Subsonic based CMS for 3.*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subsonic 3 is merely used to provide Data Access and class mapping through t4 templates. There  is no CMS.

The worrying sentence in your question is " If its not CMS based then from where i can get it?". If its not cms based then you can't get it from anywhere. It doesn't exist.